# Datagridview change format of date column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, date-format

I am trying to change the format of a datagridview column which contains a date.

I have figured this out so far;

```
// Format how the release column is displayed
this.grillDataGridView.Columns["Released"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

The error I get is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I am pretty new to programming so any help is valuable to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that there aren't any columns in your datagridview when you run the code, so make sure the datagridview has some data before you use that.